# How to access something in a array?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Here is my code

```
const [vaccines, setVaccines] = useState([]);
```

```
<Select className="input" placeholder="Todo..." options={todo.notdone} />
```

but it the UI says no options I think the error is at todo.notdone how do I fix this?

Comment: Need more code to debug. Where is todo initialized ?

Comment: What is on line 199 of `App.js`?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add `todo` in the snippet, anyways `todo.notdone` should be an array, then it'll work.